# How to I get the < and > symbols out of my name? Also, how do I get a space in the picture below?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I started a Minecraft server and just got the GroupManager plugin to work, so how to I get the circled < and > signs away? And also insert a space there? Whenever I do a space, it just doesn't work.
[image: The Picture]

Comment: These characters outline your username, to avoid confusion. They're not "part of your name", they're only used in chat.

Comment: @Ben "Well ok," Mr. Quotes! Anyways how do I get rid of them. (I know they are not part of my name, my name is VoidChaos. But I don't know which term to use, and you didn't supply one for me to edit with, so ok.) Anyway, how do I take them away?

Comment: What's the server IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `EssentialsChat.jar` and `Essentials.jar` installed, there is a setting in the `config.yml` file.

Scroll down until you see the line with chat formatting. It will look like this:

```
format: '<{DISPLAYNAME}> {MESSAGE}'
```

Change to your likings. Color codes are supported. You said in the question you wanted this:

```
format: '{DISPLAYNAME} {MESSAGE}'
```

Color codes are also supported:

```
format: '&7{DISPLAYNAME} &7{MESSAGE}'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are an admin on the server, you can do `/me`***`yourmessage`***, and you'll get rid of the `<>`, but add a `*` at the beginning of your name.

Comment: Cool! But I was wondering if there is a way to just do it without the /me command.

Comment: I don't think so